# Stata: Mixed vs. XTMixed

Tags: stata, mixed-models

Can anyone describe the difference between the Mixed and XTMixed commands in STATA? I'm using STATA 14.2, and I get different results when I fit my multi-level model using each command.

Apologies if this is a silly or obvious question - thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you please post some example of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current Stata's [help](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?xtmixed) provides some insight here:

> `xtmixed` has been renamed to mixed.  `xtmixed` continues to work but, as
>   of Stata 13, is no longer an official part of Stata.  This is the
>   original help file, which we will no longer update, so some links may
>   no longer work.